# use entire color palette for linear gradient in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, gradient, palette

Is there a quick way to apply an entire color palette to a linear gradient in Inkscape?

I built a custom .gpl file which is available along with the native palettes.

However, I can't see where I can assign an entire palette to a gradient. Is this possible?
Without creating individual stops for each palette color? (there are 41 colors in my palette)

I'm running v1.1

Cheers

**added 2021-08-02**

Here's some python code to output formatted tags (as @Xrott's web tool will do):

```
# works for a list of rgb tuples with integer values

rgb_tup_lst =[(127, 0, 0), (138, 0, 0), (150, 0, 0)]
stops = [(n/len(rgb_tup_lst)) for n,i in enumerate(rgb_tup_lst)]
stops_rgb_lst =  list(zip(stops, rgb_tup_lst))
for s in stops_rgb_lst:
    print("<stop offset='{}' stop-color='rgb{}'/>".format(round(s[0],3), s[1]))
```

Then, can copy and past from your IDE and follow directions from @Xrott's [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/152045/161316)...please be sure to still upvote their answer if you find my python code helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a script. For every color in your .gpl file, output a line like this:

```
<stop offset="[i / (length - 1)]" stop-color="rgb([r], [g], [b])"/>
```

[I created a quick little online tool to convert your .gpl file to SVG gradient-stops.](https://output.jsbin.com/telelen/)

Then create a placeholder-gradient in Inkscape, save and open your file in a text-editor and replace the `<stop>`-tags inside the placeholder `<linearGradient>` with your generated stops.

Now you can reload your file and continue editing in Inkscape.

Comment: Nice!  Thank-you. Your online tool and text editor approach works nice (and quick) for me.  I'm intrigued by scripting directly, but I looked up the Inkscape wiki and it'd take me a bit longer to figure-out so didn't attempt (I've got good python skills, just haven't tried with Inkscape...yet).  Cheers